# VirtualBox internal network

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm trying to set up a network between virtual machines in VirtualBox. I've created different VMs including Windows XP, Windows Server 2008 R2. That's what my question is about. I want to connect Windows XP and Windows Server. How can I do that? I've searched for solutions, but couldn't find suitable one. Please give me step by step explanation or any links related to my question.
I'm using Windows 7 as a host OS.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings panel of the VM and in the network tab, select Bridged adapter and select your NIC.

[image]

Now XP and Server 2008 are linked via LAN.

Comment: It worked. I want to ask one more. How to connect with _Internal Network adapter_? Bets regards

Comment: @CodeManiac http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html see here for more info.